# Wrapping an ngRepeat inside another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to write a paginator as a directive for my application, but I can't seem to get it to work. Every where I've looked suggests using `$compile`, but I can't get that to work at all.

This is what I have, and you can view a live demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hAIozU1VxaieKzQj8Kn5?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
});

app.directive('myPaginator', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    priority : 1000,

    scope : {
      items : '=myPaginator'
    },

    controller : function($scope) {
      $scope.amount = 5;
    }
  };
});

app.directive('myPaginatorItem', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    require  : '^myPaginator',
    priority : 999,

    compile : function(element) {
      element
        .removeAttr('my-paginator-item')
        .attr('ng-repeat', 'item in items | limitTo:amount');

      return function($scope, element) {
        $compile(element)($scope);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

As you can probably tell, I'm quite new to angular, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it work by storing the data on the main directive's controller, rather than on the scope, which you can see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eTeXdURhuoSVAMQHM3LK?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
});

app.directive('myPaginator', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    priority : 1000,
    replace  : true,

    scope : {
      items : '=myPaginator'
    },

    controller : function($scope) {
      this.items = $scope.items;
      this.amount = 5;
    }
  };
});

app.directive('myPaginatorItem', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    require  : '^myPaginator',
    priority : 999,
    scope    : {},

    compile : function(element) {


      element
        .removeAttr('my-paginator-item')
        .attr('ng-repeat', 'item in paginator.items | limitTo:paginator.amount');

      return function($scope, element, $attrs, paginator) {
        $scope.paginator = paginator;
        $compile(element)($scope);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You have two major problems here:

First, Your directives doesn't share the same scope:

[image]

Second, Inside you directive you refer to an outer scope variable `items`:

```
.attr('ng-repeat', 'item in items | limitTo:amount');
```

Comment: Yes they don't share the same scope, but how come the second scope has items but not amount, whereas the first scope has both. Is there are way to make the 2nd scope a child of the first? Also, how would you do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It just gets items from the parent scope because its not isolated. Please provide more details of what you want to achieve

Comment: Also why is referring to an outer scope variable an issue? Items is available, amount isn't because the 2nd scope is not a child for some reason, even though it should be?

Comment: I'd like to make the 2nd scope a child of the 1st one, so all properties available on the 1st scope are also available on the 2nd

Comment: Or to make them share a scope